# How can I check for a file size and add that result in an Excel spreadsheet in Perl?

Tags: perl, unix, shell, ksh

Currently I monitoring a particular file with a simple shell one-liner:

```
filesize=$(ls -lah somefile |  awk '{print $5}')
```

I'm aware that Perl has some nice modules to deal with Excel files so the idea is to, let's say, run that check daily, perhaps with cron, and write the result on a spreadsheet for further statistical use.

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: I think the question is, Can you please do this for me? :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can check the size of the file using the -s operator.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Slurp qw(read_file write_file);
use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel;
use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::SaveParser;
use Spreadsheet::WriteExcel;

my $file       = 'path_to_file';
my $size_file  = 'path_to_file_keeping_the_size';
my $excel_file = 'path_to_excel_file.xls';

my $current_size = -s $file;
my $old_size = 0;
if (-e $size_file) {
   $old_size = read_file($size_file);
}

if ($old_size new;
        my $excel = $parser->Parse($excel_file);
        my $row = 1;
        $row++ while $excel->{Worksheet}[0]->{Cells}[$row][0];
        $excel->AddCell(0, $row, 0, scalar(localtime));
        $excel->AddCell(0, $row, 1, $current_size);

        my $workbook = $excel->SaveAs($excel_file);
        $workbook->close;

    } else {
        my $workbook  = Spreadsheet::WriteExcel->new($excel_file);
        my $worksheet = $workbook->add_worksheet();
        $worksheet->write(0, 0, 'Date');
        $worksheet->write(0, 1, 'Size');

        $worksheet->write(1, 0, scalar(localtime));
        $worksheet->write(1, 1, $current_size);
        $workbook->close;
    }
}

write_file($size_file, $current_size);
```

A simple way to write Excel files would be using
[Spreadsheet::Write](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Spreadsheet-Write/).
but if you need to update an existing Excel file you should look into
[Spreadsheet::ParseExcel](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Spreadsheet-ParseExcel/).

Comment: I think I'd have to do both, first create the spreadsheet then update it daily with the new size. May I ask you how could I deal with those modules in principle if I'm not the UNIX admin and I can't install new ones?

Comment: Maybe it's easier to create a CSV file. These can be loaded by Excel and are easy to generate using Perl without extra modules.

Answer (score 8):

You can use [the `-s` operator](http://p3rl.org/-X) to obtain the size of a file and the [Spreadsheet::ParseExcel](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Spreadsheet::ParseExcel) and [Spreadsheet::WriteExcel](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Spreadsheet::WriteExcel) modules to produce an updated spreadsheet with the information. [Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::SaveParser](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::SaveParser) lets you easily combine the two, in case you want to update an existing file with new information. If you are on Windows, you may want to automate Excel itself instead, probably with the aid of [Win32::OLE](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Win32::OLE).

Answer (score 4):

You can also skip the hassle of writing .xls format files and use a more generic (but sufficiently Excel-friendly) format such as CSV:

```
#!/bin/bash
date=`date +%Y/%m/%d:%H:%M:%S`
size=$(ls -lah somefile |  awk '{print $5}')
echo "$date,$size"
```

Then, in your crontab:

```
0 0 * * * /path/to/script.sh >/data/sizelog.csv
```

Then you import that .csv file into Excel just like any other spreadsheet.

Comment: How could I strip the magnitude "M" from the variable so I'd use it for comparisons, e.g. "if [$size -gt 500] then"

Comment: Nano: the "-h" argument to ls is what puts it in K/M/G format. Changing the "ls -lah" to "ls -la" would list the size in bytes without a magnitude.

Answer (score 4):

Perl also has the very nice (and very *fast*) [Text::CSV_XS](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=text%3A%3Acsv_xs&mode=module) which allows you to easily make Excel-friendly CSV files, which may be a better solution than creating proper XLS files.

For example (over-commented for instructional value):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
package main;
use strict; use warnings; # always!

use Text::CSV_XS;
use IO::File;

# set up the CSV file
my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new( {eol=>"\r\n"} );
my $io  = IO::File->new( 'report.csv', '>')
  or die "Cannot create report.csv: $!\n";

# for each file specified on command line
for my $file (@ARGV) {
    unless ( -f $file ) {
        # file doesn't exist
        warn "$file doesn't exist, skipping\n";
        next;
    }

    # get its size
    my $size = -s $file;

    # write the filename and size to a row in CSV
    $csv->print( $io, [ $file, $size ] );
}

$io->close; # make sure CSV file is flushed and closed
```

Comment: One of the nice things about this approach is the output is human readable.

Answer (score 2):

The module you should be using is [Spreadsheet::WriteExcel](http://search.cpan.org/~jmcnamara/Spreadsheet-WriteExcel/lib/Spreadsheet/WriteExcel.pm).